# Is there a way I could put this error into a variable in python?

Tags: python, try-catch

I have the code here:

```
import traceback

try:
    raise TypeError("Oups!")
except Exception as err:
    try:
        raise TypeError("Again !?!")
    except:
        pass
    traceback.print_tb(err.__traceback__)
```

I am not sure how I could put the error into a variable with the same format. The error looks like:

```
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/file.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise TypeError("Oups!")
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

The raise keyword throws the exception upwards, here quitting the programm as it reaches top level.
You can save an exception like any other type as its just a class. Try this:
`smthing = TypeError("new error")`

Comment: That only returns `new error`, not the formatted error.

Comment: Obviously it also works with the variable err.